# SSIS won't connect to Oracle issue after ODAC driver un-install & re-install

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, oracle-11g

I installed the ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit drivers and client and could successfully connect SSIS to an Oracle database.

I noticed that the installation had defaulted to the E: drive which is where the data files are on that server.

In the spirit of trying to follow best practice I uninstalled ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit and reinstalled them in the correct drive D:

When I try and connect SSIS to oracle again it fails with the following error message:

"Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019"

I set up the TNS Names in ODBC DataSources and can connect successfully when I test there. So it seems like the problem is in VS / SSIS

Has anybody experienced this before? Any ideas?

Cheers,

Lins